# I can not change the DOM using the cache?

Tags: php, html, caching, yii

I'm using Yii2 framework.

**I have a code:**

```
$loading = Url::home() . "image.gif";
$data = PhpSimple\HtmlDomParser::str_get_html($result);
$dataSrc = 'data-src';
$selectors = explode(", ", $this->selector);
foreach ($selectors as $selector) {
  $cacheKey = "Ca::" . $selector . "::" . Yii::$app->request->url;
  $dataSelector = Yii::$app->cache->get($cacheKey);
  $arrImages = $data->find($selector." img");
  if ($dataSelector === false) {
    foreach ($arrImages as $img) {
        $img->$dataSrc = $img->src;
        $img->src = $loading;
        $var = "<noscript><img src=" . $img->$dataSrc . " /></noscript>";
        $img->outertext = $img->outertext . $var;
    }
    Yii::$app->cache->set($cacheKey, $arrImages, DAY, $this->dependency);
  }
  else{
      $arrImages = $dataSelector;
  }
}
return parent::afterAction($action, $data);
```

> $selector = 'div.main, div.part__a';

**What do I need:** 
I need to when you first visit the page selectors that I pass in IMG tags changed attributes and add new tags updated selectors were recorded in the cache. That when you next visit, data selectors are not changed, but were taken from the cache.

**What I have:**
At the first visit, the selectors are changed and stored in the cache, the page is displayed correctly. On subsequent calls, the data from the cache does not come into the house and the selectors do not change ...

**Question:**
What do I need to change to the data from the cache selectors correctly replaced the original data?

*If you need any data, I can write.*